# Image not showing in render as pdf..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have created a VF page as render as PDF..I am creating PDF from Opportunity and showing all products and total price in PDF..Everything is coming fine except the product image which is coming from Product.

I have a formula field on Opportunity Product

**ProductImage__c**

```
IF(PricebookEntry.Product2.DefaultImageId__c == null, 
IMAGE("/resource/defaultProductImage", "No Product Image", 75, 75), 
IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + PricebookEntry.Product2.DefaultImageId__c, "Image", 75, 75))
```

In DefaultImageId__c i have image recordid.

**VF Page**

```
  <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="line">
      <tr>
         <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.Name}</td>
         <td>{!line.Description}</td>
         <td ALIGN="center">

        **<img src='{!line.ProductImage__c}'/>**

          </td>            
         <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>
         <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.UnitPrice}"/></td>
         <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.TotalPrice}"/></td>
      </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
```

My image in PDF is broken.Can someone please hemp me out why image link is broken.

I will really appreciate any help...

Comment: Does the image appear correctly in the Visualforce page if you don't render it as a PDF?

Comment: No..it is not appearing in VF page and render as pdf..I  don't know why..?

Comment: If it isn't appearing in the HTML version of the Visualforce page I'd check the URL that is being returned in the `img` tag. Is it referencing a valid URL and image?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!line.ProductImage__c}" escape="false"/>
```

I have used this and its working perfectly.

Thanks